# Can you install a wildcard SSL and single EV SSL together for the same domain?

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate

I currently have a EV Premium SSL from godaddy.com for www.mydomain.com

Is it possible to install a wildcard SSL together with a EV Premium SSL?

www.mydomain.com is my main SSL as customers see it with the green bar and company name etc.

However, elements on my webpage are loaded from:
css.mydomain.com
js.mydomain.com
img.mydomain.com
etc

I would not like to get a Premium SSL for each since it would cost too much, and in any case customers don't go to pages via those domains. I need to have a SSL on them as Internet Explorer will show SSL mixed content error messages without it.

I currently run a a WHM/cPanel CentOS server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No you cant. At least not on the same IP address/port number combo.
When the client connects you can present one and only one certificate.

You can however set up it on another (nonstandard) port or even better on another IP with a standart ssl port.

Then you can configure which cert to use for each one (of the two).

Comment: This is not a problem, the other subdomains are already on a different IP.

Answer (score 0):

**I think you can!** As long as you use separate server-settings for the different (sub)domains and your server supports HTTP/1.1 (or SPDY as in example below).

For example, in NGINX you could make different `server{}` blocks to address different (sub)domains, using different certificates.

```
server {
    server_name
            www.mydomain.com;

    ## Set 1st SSL for www.
    listen                          443 ssl spdy;
    spdy_headers_comp               5;
    ssl_certificate_key             /etc/ssl/domain/www-mydomain-com.key;
    ssl_certificate                 /etc/ssl/domain/www-mydomain-com-unified.crt;
    ssl_dhparam                     /etc/ssl/domain/dhparam.pem;
    ssl_stapling                    on;
    ssl_stapling_verify             on;
    resolver                        8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4 valid=300s;
    resolver_timeout                5s;

    root /var/www/www.mydomain.com/public;
    index                                   index.php index.html;
    ## etcetera
}
```

And set another:

```
server {
    server_name
            sub.mydomain.com;

    ## Set 2nd SSL for sub.
    listen                          443 ssl spdy;
    spdy_headers_comp               5;
    ssl_certificate_key             /etc/ssl/domain/sub-mydomain-com.key;
    ssl_certificate                 /etc/ssl/domain/sub-mydomain-com-unified.crt;
    ssl_dhparam                     /etc/ssl/domain/dhparam.pem;
    ssl_stapling                    on;
    ssl_stapling_verify             on;
    resolver                        8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4 valid=300s;
    resolver_timeout                5s;

    root /var/www/sub.mydomain.com/public;
    index                                   index.php index.html;
    ## etcetera
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've tested using separate server settings `server{}`, which I thought would work as well, but it doesn't seem to work. The Nginx configuration is being read from top to bottom so it reads the first `server {listen 443 ;` and then terminates there.

In short, I think you'd need to have an individual IP specified in order for this to work.

Ex:

```
server {
        listen          162.00.00.00:443;
        server_name     domain.com;
}

server {
        listen          192.11.11.11:443 ;
        server_name     subdomain.domain.com;
}
```